# How to use API gateway as target endpoint in APIGEE

Tags: apigee, aws-api-gateway

I have so far seen no online resources to invoke a `AWS API gateway API` from `APIGEE`. I always get the following when i trace

```
{
"fault": {
    "faultstring": "The Service is temporarily unavailable",
    "detail": {
        "errorcode": "messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ServiceUnavailable"
    }
}
```

I have followed the following resource from APIGEE webinars here [link](http://apigee.com/about/blog/developer/bringing-api-management-aws-powered-backends)
and was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your API invocation endpoint in API Gateway as target endpoint in APIGEE like a HTTP proxy.

Comment: I tried this. But, it keeps on throwing me a handshake failure error. I have fixed that by adding truststore in my default.xml. But, now this error shows up "Security store apigee-aws is not configured in environment"

Answer (score 0):

Doing a callout to the AWS api is tricky because you'll need to generate an access token.

It might be easier to orchestrate that in a JavaScript callout to make the call (so you can calculate headers and your SHA keys) then set the token as a flow variable and do your callouts from there.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of API Gateway integration, at a minimum the APIGEE client will need to be configured to:

1. Support SNI
2. Sign the request with AWS SigV4 if "AWS_IAM" auth is enabled for the API method

SSL handshake failures are often a result of missing SNI support in the client.

Any APIGEE implementation specifics may be better fielded by APIGEE support.

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score -1):

For Apigee, if you are on the Free plan there is no SNI support. So if you are trying to make an HTTPS request it won't happen, you'll need to upgrade your account to make it work.

You can find more details from Apigee here: https://community.apigee.com/questions/9237/apigee-proxie-with-amazon-gateway-api-503-service.html